# How to write Int32 to NSOutputStream in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to write an Int32 to an NSOutputStream in Swift and I'm having difficulties.  In ObjC, I would have done something like this:

```
-(void)write4ByteField:(int32_t)value {
    [stream write:((value >> 24) & 0xff)];
    [stream write:((value >> 16) & 0xff)];
    [stream write:((value >> 8) & 0xff)];
    [stream write:(value & 0xff)];
}
```

However, in Swift, it really doesn't like me doing all of that low-level bit-shifting and I gave up on casting the values all over the place.

I tried something like:

```
func write4ByteField(value: Int32) {
    stream.write(&value, maxLength: sizeof(Int32))
}
```

but I get an error `int16 is not convertible to @lvalue inout $T4`

Similarly, if I try to go to NSData I get the same error:

```
func write4ByteField(value: Int32) {
    let data = NSData(bytes: &value, length: sizeof(Int32)
    stream.write(data.bytes, maxLength: sizeof(Int32))
}
```

Any suggestions?  I'm guessing I am just going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last approach is almost correct. `value` needs to be a *variable* parameter
so that you can use it as "in-out expression" `&value`, and `data.bytes` needs a cast:

```
func write4ByteField(var value: Int32) {
    let data = NSData(bytes: &value, length: sizeof(Int32))
    stream.write(UnsafePointer(data.bytes), maxLength: sizeof(Int32))
}
```

It can also be done without `NSData`, including the conversion to big-endian
byte order:

```
func write4ByteField(value: Int32) {
    var valueBE = value.bigEndian
    withUnsafePointer(&valueBE) { 
        self.stream.write(UnsafePointer($0), maxLength: sizeofValue(valueBE))
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  I think the main thing I was missing is I've never seen the `withUnsafePointer` construct.  Very useful for interacting with other ObjC APIs I've been struggling with that want an `inout` pointer.

Comment: Finally I fonud it. +1