# Wrong bytes generated to create WAV file

Tags: swift, avfoundation, nsdata, byte-shifting

My app needs to generate a audio file and I'm writing the file generator following my last Android version. On Android it uses [OKIO](https://github.com/square/okio) to deal with IO and iOS it uses the native NSData.

Every WAV file needs a header to inform some parameters for the data reader (media player).

It uses this file generator, writing bytes following some specifications provided on the internet.

```
//Audio file content, this variable will be used
//to storage the audio data (PCM).
var content = [UInt8]() //This is not empty.
var fileSize: Int = 0 //this is not zero.

//Total size of the file, with the header.
let totalFileSize = fileSize + HEADER_SIZE

//Header data
let header = NSMutableData()

//RIFF
header.append([UInt8]("RIFF".utf8), length: 4)

//Size of the entity file
header.append(Data(bytes: readInt(Int32(totalFileSize).littleEndian)))

//WAVE
header.append([UInt8]("WAVE".utf8), length: 4)

//FMT
header.append([UInt8]("fmt ".utf8), length: 4)

//BITRATE
header.append(Data(bytes: readInt(BITRATE.littleEndian)))

//Audio format
var audioFormat = AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM.littleEndian
header.append(&audioFormat, length: 2)

//Number of channels
var audioChannels = CHANNELS.littleEndian
header.append(&audioChannels, length: 2)

//Sample rate
var sampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE.littleEndian
header.append(&sampleRate, length: 4)

//Byte rate
var byteRate = ((SAMPLE_RATE*UInt32(CHANNELS)*UInt32(BYTES_PER_SAMPLE))/UInt32(8)).littleEndian
header.append(&byteRate, length: 4)

//Block align
var blockAlign = (UInt16(CHANNELS) * UInt16(BYTES_PER_SAMPLE) / UInt16(8)).littleEndian
header.append(&blockAlign, length: 2)

//Bytes per sample
var bytesPerSample = BYTES_PER_SAMPLE.littleEndian
header.append(&bytesPerSample, length: 2)

//Data
header.append([UInt8]("data".utf8), length: 4)

//Size of the audio data
var sizeLittleEndian = UInt32(fileSize).littleEndian
header.append(&sizeLittleEndian, length: 4)

print(header.length) //44
```

It uses this method to write Int on the buffer:

```
func readInt(_ i: Int32) -> [UInt8] {
  return [UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: (i >> 24) & 0xff),
          UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: (i >> 16) & 0xff),
          UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: (i >>  8) & 0xff),
          UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: (i      ) & 0xff)]
}
```

On Android, the file is being generated without any problem. But on iOS these 2 parameters are wrong. Look (Most top file generated on Android code and the bottom was generated by iOS code):

[image]

Swift 3

I really don't know what is happening, can you help me?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Yes :) Solved!!

Comment: Can you post the answer here?

Answer (score 4):

One of the main issues is that the `readInt` function is returning big-endian, it needs to be little-endian.

Anyway, this worked for me. This is how I initialize a WAV file. Hope it helps someone.

```
func createHeader() {

    let sampleRate:Int32 = 44100
    let chunkSize:Int32 = 36
    let subChunkSize:Int32 = 16
    let format:Int16 = 1
    let channels:Int16 = 1
    let bitsPerSample:Int16 = 16
    let byteRate:Int32 = sampleRate * Int32(channels * bitsPerSample / 8)
    let blockAlign: Int16 = channels * 2
    let dataSize:Int32 = 0

    let header = NSMutableData()

    header.append([UInt8]("RIFF".utf8), length: 4)
    header.append(intToByteArray(chunkSize), length: 4)

    //WAVE
    header.append([UInt8]("WAVE".utf8), length: 4)

    //FMT
    header.append([UInt8]("fmt ".utf8), length: 4)

    header.append(intToByteArray(subChunkSize), length: 4)
    header.append(shortToByteArray(format), length: 2)
    header.append(shortToByteArray(channels), length: 2)
    header.append(intToByteArray(sampleRate), length: 4)
    header.append(intToByteArray(byteRate), length: 4)
    header.append(shortToByteArray(blockAlign), length: 2)
    header.append(shortToByteArray(bitsPerSample), length: 2)


    header.append([UInt8]("data".utf8), length: 4)

    header.append(intToByteArray(dataSize), length: 4)

    header.write(to: fileURL!, atomically: true)

}

func intToByteArray(_ i: Int32) -> [UInt8] {
    return [
            //little endian
            UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: (i      ) & 0xff),
            UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: (i >>  8) & 0xff),
            UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: (i >> 16) & 0xff),
            UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: (i >> 24) & 0xff)
    ]
}

func shortToByteArray(_ i: Int16) -> [UInt8] {
    return [
        //little endian
        UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: (i      ) & 0xff),
        UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: (i >>  8) & 0xff)
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The written `totalFileSize` looks big endian on iOS while on Android it's small. Maybe you're `.littleEndian`ing it twice?

The iOS `data` block doesn't look right either, on Android there are plausible sample values after `data`, but on iOS it looks like you've taken the address of some CoreAudio structure (maybe an `AudioUnit`? an `ExtAudioFile`? an `AudioConverter`?).

Comment: I removed the code that provides the data. But it simply read a PCM file, get bytes and and these bytes on a temporary buffer.

Comment: About the first question,  I really don't know, is this related with the value or the position?

Comment: ah, you've written the header of a `.caf` file into your wav file. that's not going to end well.  yes, the `.caf` file is lpcm, but what format? you will likely need to decode it first. the value of `totalFileSize` is wrong in the wav file

Comment: No, this is writing a PCM file, the recorder uses `kAudioFormatLinearPCM` as format, bitrate: 16000 and sample rate: 44100.
The problem is not only related with the value of `totalFileSize`, but with `header.append(Data(bytes: readInt(BITRATE.littleEndian)))` too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593831/how-to-write-int32-to-nsoutputstream-in-swift